# Chrome DevTools Protocol: How to unsubscribe Page.javascriptDialogOpening event

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol

I am using the Chrome DevTools Protocol API functions to listen to the `javascriptDialogOpening` event. Below is the code.

```js
async navigate(url: URL, target: any) {

  const { Page } = target.connection;

  // Enable the required protocol features
  await Page.enable();

  // Add a listener and handler for JavaScript dialogs
  Page.javascriptDialogOpening(async(event: Protocol.Page.JavascriptDialogOpeningEvent) => {

  // Respond with a confirmation to all dialogs
  const dialogResponse: Protocol.Page.HandleJavaScriptDialogRequest = {
      'accept': true
    };

  Page.handleJavaScriptDialog(dialogResponse);
  });
}
```

I got an error: MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 `Page.javascriptDialogOpening` listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Answer (score 1):

By putting the `javascriptDialogOpening` event registration in the `navigate` handler, you are adding the handler over and over again. Because every time a navigation event happens, you are re-adding this event handler.

What you really want here is to put the `javascriptDialogOpening` event registration in your initialization code. If you do this, it will be registered only once and you will no longer have this issue.

```
CDP({'host': host, 'port': port}, (client) => {
// ...
    Page.javascriptDialogOpening((params) => {
      Page.handleJavaScriptDialog({'accept': true});
    });
```